# How to convert a JSON result to Parquet in python?

Tags: python, json, parquet

Follow the script below to convert a JSON file to parquet format. I am using the pandas library to perform the conversion.
However the following error is occurring: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'schema'
I am still new to python.

Here's the original json file I'm using:
[
    {
        "a": "01",
        "b": "teste01"
    },
    {
        "a": "02",
        "b": "teste02"
    }
]

What am i doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

df = pd.read_json('C:/python/json_teste')

pq = pa.parquet.write_table(df, 'C:/python/parquet_teste')
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-1b4ced833098> in <module>
----> 1 pq = pa.parquet.write_table(df, 'C:/python/parquet_teste')

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\parquet.py in write_table(table, where, row_group_size, version, use_dictionary, compression, write_statistics, use_deprecated_int96_timestamps, coerce_timestamps, allow_truncated_timestamps, data_page_size, flavor, filesystem, **kwargs)
   1256     try:
   1257         with ParquetWriter(
-> 1258                 where, table.schema,
   1259                 filesystem=filesystem,
   1260                 version=version,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5065             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5066                 return self[name]
-> 5067             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5068 
   5069     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'schema'
```

Print file:

```
#print 
print(df)
   a        b
0  1  teste01
1  2  teste02

#following columns
df.columns
Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')

#following types
df.dtypes
a     int64
b    object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also directly read JSON files utilizing `pyarrow` as in the following example:

```
from pyarrow import json
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table = json.read_json('C:/python/json_teste') 
pq.write_table(table, 'C:/python/result.parquet')  # save json/table as parquet
```

Reference: [reading and writing with pyarrow.parquet](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#reading-and-writing-single-files)

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve what you are looking for by pyspark as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("JsonToParquetPysparkExample") \
    .getOrCreate()

json_df = spark.read.json("C://python/test.json", multiLine=True,) 
json_df.printSchema()
json_df.write.parquet("C://python/output.parquet")
```

Comment: Do you have to set up a spark cluster for this?

Comment: yes you would. py arrow read_json or from_pydict would be easier i think out of the two

Answer (score 4):

If your motive is to just convert json to parquet, you can probably use pyspark API:

```
>>> data = [ { "a": "01", "b": "teste01" }, { "a": "02", "b": "teste02" } ]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
>>> df.write.parquet("data.parquet")
```

Now, this DF is a spark dataframe, which can be saved in parquet.

Comment: I imported pyspark the script and when executing this script the following error occurred: AttributeError: module 'pyspark' has no attribute 'createDataFrame'.

Comment: You need to start a pyapark she'll to test this. createDataFrame is a method on spark which comes by default on pyspark shell.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But i started a pyapark she'll to test and had this error again. I am using the jupyter notebook. Follow the code:                                   
import pyspark
data = [ { "a": "01", "b": "teste01" }, { "a": "02", "b": "teste02" } ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.write.parquet("data.parquet")

Comment: what version of pyspark are you using? I believe spark.createDataFrame is available 2.3.0 onward, have a look in this doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema

Comment: @MateusSilvestre Take a look at this in order to instantiate `spark`: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

Comment: @MateusSilvestre try this https://gist.github.com/zackster/183b2729abbe0553abfec82a566c0f92

Comment: @MateusSilvestre I have provided a complete example for your ask. please take a look and see if it works

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to convert a JSON file to Apache Parquet format, using Pandas in Python. This is an easy method with a well-known library you may already be familiar with.

Firstly, make sure to install `pandas` and `pyarrow`. If you're using [Python with Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#Downloads):

```
conda install pandas
conda install pyarrow
```

Then, here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_json(FILEPATH_TO_JSON_FILE)
data.to_parquet(PATH_WHERE_TO_SAVE_PARQUET_FILE)
```

I hope this helps, please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow, the library you are using shows that in example that you need to write the column names in the data frame.
Try using column names of your data frame and it will work.

```
# Given PyArrow schema
import pyarrow as pa
schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field('my_column', pa.string),
    pa.field('my_int', pa.int64),
])
convert_json(input_filename, output_filename, schema)
```

reference: [json2parquet](https://pypi.org/project/json2parquet/)